# Dynamic type in c

Tags: c, gcc, typeof

We all know that there is no dynamic type in c programming language.But with the help of `typeof` operator in GCC,we can implement some dynamic type characteristic with c programming language.Recently I read the souce code of `talloc`,and found that they do it gracefully.

---

Questions:

- In which scenario should we use the `typeof` skill?
- Please give me more example,especially technique used in the Linux kernel.(Except the `the container_of()` marco)

Comment: Clearly, one answer to your first question is "only when you never expect the code to be compiled by a compiler other than GCC".

Comment: Yes,I use GCC both in Windows and Linux.

Comment: For second sentence in your original question "we can implement some ...", typeof is a macro which is evaluated at compile time. Dynamic  typing refers to some thing evaluated at run time. You probably can implement some thing similar to RTTI that exists in c++ in c as well. The basic idea is to have a maximum sized variable to contain any data, and then examine it's bytes at run time to determine what type of value is actually stored in it. For e.g. allocate space equal to a long double, then identify on run time, if it actually contains a char, short, int, float or double at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof` is a compile-time construct provided by GCC as an extension. It might be used to write safe macros, like the example in the gcc manual:

```
#define max(a,b) \
({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

As you mention the Linux kernel, the `container_of()` macro is a good example of the use of `typeof()` construct. Its heavily used for implementing subclassing, e.g. in device drivers.

Another example in the kernel is in data structures, like linked lists, where lists are embedded.

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Comment: For the source of `container_of`,I read it a few days ago.More example ,please!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like one possible usage would be analogous to C++ templates according to this link http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

So, you could create a templatized C function to return the minimum value of an array based on a specified type. I am sure that there are far reaching implications of this operator.

Comment: What about question two?

Comment: Serendipitously, I was right. The Linux kernel uses macros to find the min or max of two values utilizing the typeof keyword. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h